# Can I connect a external network adapter to Window Server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server

I want to connect an external Wi-Fi adapter from my local PC to a Windows Server in AWS.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are wanting to make your local wifi (eg at home or in the office) accessible to an Amazon EC2 Windows instance.

This is **not** a capability provided by AWS.

You *might* be able to find a software product that can **extend a USB device or a network connection between two computers across the Internet**. For example, I have seen people use a virtual serial port to allow a "dongle" to be connected to a virtual computer. However, any such solution is something you would configure in the Windows operating system and your own computer. It would not have anything specific to do with Amazon EC2.